# How to exclude directories starting with "."

Tags: python

I have a list of dir and i need exclude the dir with dot

```
['.DS_Store', 'Five', 'Four', 'Instructions.txt', 'One', 'Three', 'Two']
```

and then make for loop through the dir

```
import os
import re
from os import walk

arr_dir  = os.listdir()
print(arr_dir)

arr_dir.sort()
print(arr_dir)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add a condition into a list-comprehension

```
arr_dir  = [d for d in os.listdir() if not d.startswith(".")]
```